# Is there something like VCR (http-interaction stubbing/replay) for commandline calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stub, minitest

I am developing a system that has a lot of commandline interaction. Sometimes even over SSH. Commands can take as long as 30minutes sometimes to finish.

Currently I am stubbing out most of the `system` calls on the objects doing that system call. E.g:

```
class BackupBuilderTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "it calls the backup utility over ssh" do
    BackupBuilder.expects(:system).with("ssh foo@bar backup").returns(true)
    BackupBuilder.perform(:id => @backup.id)
  end
end

BackupBuilder
  def perform
    system("ssh foo@bar backup")
  end
end
```

However, a command like `ssh foo@bar backup` can fail on a lot of levels, and will output a lot of data, which I capture and act on. It also takes a *long* time to run; not a good thing in integration tests and unacceptable in unit-tests.
I'd like to run this, whithout having all the actual `ssh` and backups running.

For HTTP there is [VCR](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs), which does nearly exactly what I'd like to do on my CLI-calls. Is there something for this? Or am I missing some pattern or common stubbing-trick that allows me to do this?

Comment: Well, this does not answer your question, but still you may find it useful: https://github.com/cucumber/aruba .

Comment: I use Aruba in several applications, but Aruba covers the excact opposite of what I want: Aruba allows you to spec and assert the outcomes of a CLI, but what I want is to _stub_ the CLI. I am not developing a CLI, but consuming it; yet want to avoid consuming it (too heavy) in my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach someone took using cram:

http://pbrisbin.com/posts/mocking_bash